# Using jQuery to alter parameters in link

Tags: jquery, parameters, replace

I am using jQuery 1.3.2 and I have an input field on my page that provides link to be copied, like this one: `http://mydomain.com/resize.php?src=http://www.externaldomain.com/content/Uploads/everydaymail.jpg&w=533&h=400&zc=1` . I would like to use jQuery and be able to change `w=533` part to `w=300`, for example and also the `h=400` to change into `h=200` . This is an image resizing script that I'm using and I want to be able to change the height and width parameters from that link in the inputbox with my desired values that are dynamic.

I am no good at regex, can anyone provide an example/suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: Note:- `jQuery 1.3.2`. This is way too old version. Use latest version.

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace , maybe?

Comment: @Harry Joy, that's the version my client is using, I'm getting it as is. Is this not possible in 1.3.2 ?

Comment: Don't really get the up-votes on the "your jQuery is too old." This is really a plain old JavaScript question...

Comment: @MannyCalavera: it might be possible in jquery 1.3.2. I'm just giving an advice. If your customer forces to use this then it. Customer is ***GOD***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
var newWVal = $('#inputfield').val().replace(/w=[\d\.]+&/g, 'w='+imageWidth+'&');
var newFinalVal = newWVal.replace(/h=[\d\.]+&/g, 'h='+imageHeight+'&');
$('#inputfield').val(newFinalVal);
```

I think the regex could be a little smarter but it also works great this way.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It's no matter what version of jQuery will be used. All version can set element attribute values. The main point here it to use Regex to parse this value and update params or just construct link from scratch.

Here is link builder: :)

```
$('#build').click(function() {

    var src = $('#src').val();
    var w = $('#w').val();
    var h = $('#h').val();

    var link = "http://mydomain.com/resize.php?src=" + src + "&w=" + w + "&h=" + h + "&zc=1";

    $('#link').attr('src', link).text(link);

});

$('#replace').click(function() {

    var src = $('#src').val();
    var w = $('#w').val();
    var h = $('#h').val();

    var link = $('#link').attr('src')

    link = link.replace(/w=\d{1,4}/i, "w=" + w)
               .replace(/h=\d{1,4}/i, "h=" + w);

    $('#link').attr('src', link).text(link);

});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/wzc8F/10/

Comment: Thanks for the functions. I see that you search for `d{1,4}`, this is an offset setting I presume and want to let you know that I do not know for sure that the width and height value would have up to 4 characters, user can input 1,2,3,4,5,6 ect. chars so that's why I need to delimit by where the next `&` appears. Thanks.

Comment: so, chage to the following: `link.replace(/w=[\w\.,]*&/i, "w=" + w + "&")`. It will selects any numbers including dots and comas till the next '&' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this code, so caveat emptor...

**Template string:**

```
var str = "http://mydomain.com/resize.php?src=http://www.externaldomain.com/content/Uploads/everydaymail.jpg&w=XXX&h=YYY&zc=1";
```

**Use as needed:**

```
str = str.replace("w=XXX", "w=your_value_here"); 
str = str.replace("h=YYY", "h=your_value_here");
```

HTH.

**EDIT:**

Okay, assuming dynamic variables:

```
var height = 42;
var width = 42;

str = str.replace( "w=XXXX", "w=" + width ); 
str = str.replace( "h=YYYY", "h=" + height );
```

Make sense?

Comment: Also, if you are printing this string out to, say, the href of a hyperlink, you'll want to replace your `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: The width and height can both be `XXXX`, 4 numbers, I have figured it out though. Thanks.

Comment: @Manny Calavera Good work. Figuring things out sooooo beats being frustrated all night... :]

Comment: Also, I do not know the actual value of the XXX/XXXX.

Comment: @Manny Calavera If their values are held in variables, just amend the code above to append the value to the end of the replacement string.

Comment: They are not, the old value is in the input's value, which I need to identify and can have length up to `XXXXXXXXXXXXX` or just `XXXXX`. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: I do know how to concatenate values, I need to find the `XXXX` and `YYYY` values first, from your example. I know my new values, I just needed a search pattern to know where to insert in the text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4015/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-manny-calavera)